# Examples of "natural" observed events (phenomena) without scientific explanation

Tags: popular-science, big-list

Could you provide me some examples of observed events considered "natural" but with no scientific explanation? I would prefer some easy-to-understand examples, not involving a lot of knowledge & math, but even the hard-to-understand ones are welcomed.

I have in mind one, although I think nowadays it may be scientifically explained: orientation and navigation of migratory birds.

Comment: By "no scientific explanation", do you mean we have to have failed to dream up a suitable explanation, or that whatever has been proposed isn't empirically substantiated yet? The latter, which allows for far more examples, is defensible because science doesn't _know_ the answer either way.

Comment: It is a little like asking are there any homework questions without answers. Yes. Some because they haven't been done yet. Come back tomorrow, we are still working on it. Some because they are too hard.

Comment: See [List of unsolved problems in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics)

Answer (score 1):

The recently released US government's report on UFO sightings:

https://edition.cnn.com/2021/06/27/politics/ufos-uap-extraterrestrial-life/index.html

Obviously, the question posed is not well-formulated [what does "natural" mean? what does "have no scientific explanation" mean? etc]. But I think this answer is in the essence of the question asked nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

There should be plenty in biology / life science. For example,

1, How do 17 year cicadas count 17?

2, Why do some people have no symptom with Covid19 while others die?

3, ...

Answer (score 0):

A couple easily accessible topics from my [PhD thesis](http://john.maloney.org/Papers/Maloney%20thesis%20final%20%28Jan%202012%29%20compressed.pdf) that I believe remain unexplained:

1. How and why do (animal) biological cells maintain their mechanical behavior, over a broad range of familiar frequencies, about a quarter to a third of the way intermediate from a solid to a liquid?
2. How and why do those cells maintain a lognormal distribution of stiffness?